# How to use SDL2 software render with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, opengl-3

I'm creating a 3D game and I'm wondering about how to mix SDL2 software (surface) render and OpenGL. I tried to render simple text using this code but it doesn't work.

```
glClearColor(0,0,1,1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
SDL_BlitSurface(surf,0,dest,0);
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Are you talking about updating the window surface via `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` & `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface()` on a SDL_Window created with the `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag?  Or just using random non-window surfaces?

Comment: I am taking about updating window surface via SDL_UpdateWindowSurface on SDL_Window created with SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL FLAG.

Comment: Nothing is preventing you from `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer` on custom surface and then feeding this surface to opengl though.

Answer (score 4):

> I am taking about updating window surface via `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` on `SDL_Window` created with `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag

That's [specifically prohibited by the API](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/0b98870c7f72/include/SDL_video.h#l831):

> You may not combine this [SDL_GetWindowSurface] with 3D or the rendering API on this window.